# MVC redirect does not navigate to a page

Tags: ajax, redirect, model-view-controller

On click on hyperlink, I want to navigate to page after applying a business logic. Currently 'return Redirect(Url)' in the mvc action does not navigate to the page.

```
$("a").bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        gotoUrl($, this.href);
    });

gotoUrl: function ($, href) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'mycontroller/myaction',
            data: { url: href },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
            success: function (data) { }          
        });
}

//mycontroller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myaction(string url)
{
    //Some business logic here to update url
    return Redirect(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the current window location, you'll need to detect that your ajax request is being redirected (and manually redirect afterwards), something that is not possible since jquery will follow the redirection. In a similar situation, I implemented the following workaround which is more general, but you can adapt it to your needs.

In global.asax create handler for Application_EndRequest, intercepting the redirect response and rewriting the response code to something else representing error, I use code 422 - Unprocessable Entity.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
 if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 302 && Context.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
 {
  Context.Response.StatusCode = 422;
 }
}
```

In your client-side script, you'll now need to detect those 422 responses by adding general ajax error handler.

```
$(document)
  .ajaxError(function (e, xhr, settings) {
    if (xhr.status == 422) {
     window.location = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location');
    }
  })
```